# Find and replace with variable

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

In `webstorm 2017.1.1` I would like to find and replace a simple string with variable in the replace, for example:

find: `testID:'`

replace: `testID:'${FILE_NAME}`

And I expect the replace result will be `testID:'MY_FILE_NAME...`

Someone know if it's possible vie webstorm or via any plugin related?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: search & replace (normal or structural) cannot resolve variables. it only knows text. It's very hard to believe that there would be a way. :(

Answer (score 1):

As [@SupunWijerathne said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44698901/find-and-replace-with-variable#comment76380710_44698901), the IDEA replace dialogue is not aware of variables. However, this is something you could easily do in a shell. For example, on Linux, and with a replacement string without any special characters, you could do this:

```
sed -i "s/testID:'/testID:'${FILE_NAME}/g" my-file.txt
```